# Get group members with an admin account / deprecated GroupsManager class

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

The class GroupsManager will be turned off by November 20, 2014 https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/domain/groups-manager

I am using this class to manage some groups with my admin account as it's allowing access to group members **WITHOUT BEING MEMBER OF**.

Sample code here:

```
var group = GroupsManager.getGroup("some-group-name@mydomain.com");
var members = group.getAllMembers();
```

Using the Groups Service https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/ is not an option, as stated in the documentation: "This service allows scripts to access Google Groups. It can be used to query information such as a group's email address, or the list of groups in **WHICH THE USER IS MEMBER OF**."

Using the **AdminSDK** as proposed in the GroupsManager "To manage your domain, use the Admin SDK Directory and Admin SDK Reports advanced services instead." is neither an option as **there is no method to retrieve the members of a group**...

So, anyone has a clue?

Thank you,
Franck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Admin SDK Directory service to do this. The method [`AdminDirectory.Members.list`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/list) lists all the members of a group.

Answer (score 0):

```
Directory service = null;
        try
            {
                HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
                JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
                GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                    .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
                    .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER))
                    .setServiceAccountUser(userEmail)
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
                        new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
                    .build();
                service = new Directory.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
                    .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).setApplicationName("ShareFileUSer").build();
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception is : "+e);
            }



    Directory.Users.List userList = service.users().list().setCustomer("my_customer").setMaxResults(100);
```