# Using adminDirectory.members results in API error

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to use the adminDirectory.members.list() method as answered here:

[Get group members with an admin account / deprecated GroupsManager class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883269/get-group-members-with-an-admin-account-deprecated-groupsmanager-class/23896788#23896788)

but I get a "Not Authorized to access this resource/api" error whenever this method is called.

The same script is making successful calls to AdminDirectory.Users.get() and so the Admin SDK appears to be authorised ok.

Any ideas?

Comment: Arg, so sorry for this. I hadn't noticed a trailing space in the email address I was passing to the function. Not convinced the error message is the most helpful but it is working now.

Comment: Can I ask you how you authorized the admin SDK? I keep getting a not authorized error when I try to use admindirectory.members.list